# logarithmic image resizing using Imagemagick?

Tags: image-processing, imagemagick, image-resizing, logarithm

I'd like to rescale an image in one dimension, using a logarithmic scale.  I've been searching for some idea on how to do this.  Some options:

1. `-evaluate` [seems to take](https://legacy.imagemagick.org/Usage/transform/#fx) `Pow` and other functions
2. `-fx` [seems to be an option](http://www.imagemagick.org/script/fx.php), and/but I'm still working to understand it

Both of the above might not be able to be passed to the `-size` or resizing operations.

Comment: Can you post an example input and output? I do not understand your last statement about -size. Please elaborate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not sure what you are asking. But here is how to apply a logarithmic transform to an image in ImageMagick. Since geometric transformations are inverse transformations (specify an output pixel and find where it comes from in the input image), we must use the inverse of the logarithm, which is the exponential. For example for a horizontal transformation:

Input:

[image]

```
convert lena.png -virtual-pixel black -fx "u.p{exp(6*i/(w-1)),j}" lena_ln.png
```

[image]

Now, if you want it to fit exactly into 256 pixels horizontally without the the black region on the right, we need to evaluate a logarithm:

```
ln(x+1) for x=0 to 255
ln(0+1) = ln(1) = 0
ln(255+1) = ln(256) = 5.545
```

Now we need the inverse operation for -fx, which is an exponential,

```
ln(x+1) = 5.545
x+1 = exp(5.545)
x = exp(5.545) - 1
```

```
convert lena.png -virtual-pixel black -fx "u.p{exp(5.545*i/(w-1))-1,j}" lena_ln2.png
```

[image]